# How to get subdirectories

Tags: c#

I have a string directory that equals a given directory. I want to cycle through that folder and all sub folders of directory. How would I be able to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3879438/272742

Comment: This is in c# by the way

Comment: Doesnt matter - turbanoff gave you correct link for C#.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [`System.IO.Directory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143314.aspx) class, which lets you get a list of files and subdirectories. You can use the overload that accepts a SearchOptions parameter to specify AllDirectories, which will fetch you all subdirectories in one go.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a fluent wrapper to do this, take a look at my blog here. http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2011/11/staticvoid-io-extentions-nuget.html

this means you can get the directory with something like this

```
new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\MyDir").Directories(d=>d.Name.StartsWith("a")).Files()
```

and other such fun things

Answer (score 0):

`Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var dir in dirctory.EnumerateDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dir.Name);
}
```